# Can't generate Java code with the bundled Jaxb for Intellij

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, xsd, jaxb

I have to modify a project using XSD validation. I had got an XML, I transformed it to XSD via Intellij and then generated the associated code with the JAXB tool. All was fine.

But for the project needs, I had to modify the entire structure of my XML, I did it. I generate the XSD as well. But, When I tried to generate the Java code via the jaxb tools, it was impossible.

When I click in this jaxb tool, it just generated another XSD.

How can I do to generate, once again, the code ?

Thank you !

There is my XSD.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="PurgeConfigurationRacine" type="PurgeConfigurationRacineType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="BusinessBaseType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="ArchiveDataOperationType" name="ArchiveDataOperation"/>
      <xs:element type="PurgeDataOperationType" name="PurgeDataOperation"/>
      <xs:element type="DeleteArchivedDataOperationType" name="DeleteArchivedDataOperation"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="dataSourceRef"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="SqlQueryType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="step" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="multi" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="param" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ArchiveDataOperationType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="SqlQueryType" name="SqlQuery" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="PurgeDataOperationType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="SqlQueryType" name="SqlQuery" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="PurgeConfigurationRacineType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="BusinessBaseType" name="BusinessBase"/>
      <xs:element type="DataBaseType" name="DataBase"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="DeleteArchivedDataOperationType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="SqlQueryType" name="SqlQuery" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="DataBaseType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="ArchiveDataOperationType" name="ArchiveDataOperation"/>
      <xs:element type="PurgeDataOperationType" name="PurgeDataOperation"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="dataSourceRef"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is a known issue, it is due to the fact that you have an attribute called `value` which is a protected name, such that you need to specify to [`xjc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html) that it has to use a different name, it can be done by adding some meta information in your XSD file as next:

```
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value" use="optional">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:property name="sqlQueryTypeValue"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
```

You will also need to add the corresponding namespace declaration and the jaxb version to use, for example:

```
<xs:schema ... xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.1">
```

More information about [how to customize JAXB binding](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I just tried your solution, but I get the same problem. But I didn't succeed to use the "http//java.sun.com/xml.ns/jaxb", Intellij proposed xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee". So I tried to rename directly the xs:attribute, and it worked... 

To you, what can be the problem during testing your initial solution ?

Thank you.